# Expectation of ratio of two distributions is the ration of the expectations

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given three random variables $X$ ,$Z$ and $Y$, does this hold in general: $E(\frac{X}{Z+X+Y})= \frac{E(X)}{E(X+Y+Z)}$? If no, then in what circumstances will this hold?

Comment: The same question applied to $\frac{X}{X^2+1}$ where the denominator and numerator are functions of random variables

Comment: This will almost never be true. What sorts of "circumstances" do you have in mind? The case where all are constants work, but I don't think many other interesting or organic circumstances will work.

Comment: Maybe I didn’t make the question clear, what I’m wondering is that if the denominator and numerator are functions of random variables, can we say the expectation of the ratio equals the ratio of expectations

Comment: I think the question is perfectly clear, but that the only circumstances where this holds are very uninteresting. This is morally similar to asking when $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: What about X and Y are independent? Can we say $E(\frac{X}{X+Y})=\frac{E(x)}{E(X+Y)}$?

Comment: It may be more instructive for you to check it yourself: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent variables that are each 1 and 2 with equal probability for a simple example. (To spoil the surprise, no.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=X+Y+Z$ and 
$$
T=\frac{X}{S}
$$
If $S$ is independent of $T$, then
$$
EX=ES\times ET
$$
and
$$
ES=\frac{EX}{ET}=\frac{EX}{EX+EY+EZ}
$$
An example of where this might arise in practice occurs in the formulation of the [dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Related_distributions)

Comment: In this case can we say$E(T)=\frac{E(X)}{E(S)}$?

Comment: This answer is good, but the independence condition you described is, I think, quite rare. (I could be wrong, of course.)